# Nautilus: move file to .folder

Tags: nautilus

Seems to be very basic, but I can't find how to move file to a .folder (hidden). I would except to have the option to type the target folder name.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to ensure "Hidden Files" is selected, so that you can see those dot-directories:

[image: Nautilus - Default]

This will give you something like:

[image: Move To - Hidden Directories]

If you don't want the hidden directories and files to be visible all the time, uncheck "Show Hidden Files". Nice and simple

Comment: And the hotkey is ctrl-H

Comment: Thanks.
The option to type path is missing for me. First in the current folder, and later in the move file command.